# Python Telegram Bot error in deleting message and sending message

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stopgame'])

def test2(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'GIOCO FINITO!')

    gamerunning = false

 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['startgame'])

def test(message):

    if(message.from_user.id == 785959524):

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'GIOCO INIZIATO!')

        gamerunning = true

    

 

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)

def echo_message(message):

    if gamerunning is true:

        d = (message[-1].message_id)

        

        if message.text.lower() in [(x)]:

            x = x+1

 

        elif message.text.lower() in ["169"]:

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Test message')

     

        else: delete_message(d,-1001681209629)
```

I can't make to work the party After "if gamerunning is true:"

Is not a bool problema, i also tried assigning a variabile ti 1 and 0

Basically Is a bot that works in a group, where people have to count, and if they don't continue correctly, the bot Will delete the message, so i give an example of a chat:

In the group:

1 (ok)

2 (ok)

3 (ok)

5 (delete)

8 (delete)

Ajdjdk (delete)

4 (ok)

[Also i get this error, but i don't know what Is causing It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmqJd.jpg)

Comment: You don’t need parenthesis around x here: “if message.text.lower() in [(x)]”

Comment: Also no need to used “if foo is True” to test for truthyness. Just do “if foo”.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you declare gamerunning `true` and `false` without capital letters. Make sure to declare them with capital letters.

Second, start with global variables for both gamerunning and x. Now you start using x without referencing it anywhere else (could be in the rest of your code, but please provide more details in the future).

*Probably this should be a comment, but I cannot comment since I am a new contributor.*